# My second Add-A-Gram

Tags: word, anagram

OK, my last one was solved in like 30 seconds, let's try for a better one.

**A pirate's favourite word** inside **the leader of an ancient pantheon** inside **moved quickly** inside **espouse one's opinions violently** inside **to increase one's skill level** inside **rice-and-cheese-based French food** inside **increased level of sour sweetness**

Comment: I would say this is a pretty nice puzzle. Don't get disheartened if your puzzle are getting solved too easily. That is because we have got some very experienced puzzlers here.

Comment: These are fine puzzles, and you like Sid said, don't worry about how quickly they're solved.  Do be aware, though, that you probably don't want to post too many in quick succession.  People will get tired of them if there are too many in a short period of time, and will probably start downvoting (or at least not upvoting).

Comment: Yeah, I'm done with these for now, unless I can think of a really really good one.  Thanks for the support guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer:

> R, RA, RAN, RANT, TRAIN, GRATIN, TANGIER

Comment: And I even did my best to use the most obscure definition of each word possible :(

Comment: Ye may think a pirate's favourite letter is R, but it's actually the C.